# How can I convert an image file to base 2 binary?

Tags: javascript, math, binary

I'm trying to do it like this:

```js
function handleFiles(files) {
  var selectedFile = files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsBinaryString(selectedFile);
  reader.onloadend = function() {
    var result = reader.result;
    convert(result);
  };
}

function convert(data) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  var result = data.toString(2);
  
  document.body.appendChild(img);
  img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + btoa(data); // this works
  
  console.log("Base ?: " + data); // not sure, I think 16 or more likely 64, 
                                  // the MDN documentation doesn't specify what base of binary is produced by the readAsBinaryString method
  console.log("Base 2: " + result); // not base 2 binary data as expected
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="input" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)">
```

This code will convert a jpeg into binary data, then render it, but it is not first converting to base 2 binary. If you run that code and look at the logs, it's something more (I'm naive on the subject of bases and binary, but my guess is base 16 or 64). I think `toString(2)` is supposed to convert to base 2, but it doesn't seem to be doing that. Before converting it back to base 64, I want to get the binary data to base 2 for experimentation.

Comment: I've read all the documentation I could find on all methods related to this and alternative options but I just can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just step through your binary string and convert each character to a binary representation?

```
function convert(data) { 
    var result = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        result += data.charCodeAt(i).toString(2)
    }
    console.log(result)
  }
```

*[ I would test this with a small file first. It writes a lot to the console, as you might imagine ]*

EDIT -- sorry, didn't realize you wanted to go back and forth. If you want to get from a binary string back to something else, you'll probably want to pad the binary with zeros so you can pull out 8 bit (or whatever) at a time:

```
function convert(data) {
    var result = ''
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
       // pad to make all binary string parts 8 bits long 
       result += data.charCodeAt(i).toString(2).padStart(8, 0)
    }
    return result
    }

function makeBuffer(string){
    buffer = ''
    for(let i = 0; i < string.length/8; i++){
        let stIdx = i*8
        // maybe a way to do this without the slice? dunno.
        buffer += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(string.slice(stIdx,stIdx+8), 2))
    }
    return buffer
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I was trying that method, but I thought it was wrong because every way I tried to get it back to base 64 afterwards failed. How can I get it back to base 64 after getting it to base 2 like that? Also getting it back to base 16 from there would work.

Comment: When I want to re-encode it with `btoa(result)` for rendering, that fails, that's my problem with this approach.

Comment: After 6 years of working with JS it still amazes me how you people so effortlessly put these solutions together. I dont know what research I could've done or what documentation I could've known to read to figure that out. I guess it's just raw experience. How long have you been coding?

Comment: @Viziionary I've been coding on and off since I was a kid in the 80s. Basic, perl, c, python, and now a lot of javascript. Dealing with things like character encodings still drives me a little nuts.

Comment: Hey, this isn't a "give me teh codez" request - just generally speaking, is it possible to achieve this without the padding? Or is that a necessity?

Comment: hmm…not sure, but I also don't know how you would know how turn the string of 1s and 0s back into anything if you didn't know if 110100011 was 1101 and 00011 or 11010 and 0011, etc. It would be the same problem with base 10 character codes. If you just had '36241' you wouldn't know if it was 36 & 241 -> '$ ñ' or 362 & 41 -> 'Ū )' without some way of knowing how wide the numbers are. That's a long way of saying, I don't really know.

Answer (score 0):

Binary is always base 2, that's what the "bi" in "binary" means.

When you call `fileReader.readAsBinaryString()` it's returning binary; Strings can store binary because they're really just an array of characters.

Displaying the string will **not** be a series of zeros and ones, it will be a jumble of different ASCII characters (letters, numbers, symbols, etc.) because those are the equivalent characters that match the binary values.

Additionally, you don't need the following line since your `data` you're passing in is already a string.

```
var result = data.toString(2);
```

Comment: I need the binary *accessible / visible* in base 2 though, for experimental purposes. Does that make sense? I want to be able to go through the data and know every 0 and 1. I get that binary is base 2, but it's not represented in base 2 here, I want to be able to loop through the data structure and read the 1s and 0s sequentially.